# Deleting old records assigned to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, destroy

My main goal is to remove old records after new records are correctly created. I tried assigning it to variable and using `#dup` method. Please look at the example code:

```
def my_method
  old_items = @user.items.dup

  new_items = @user.items.new(item_params) # one or more

  # confusing part
  old_items.destroy_all if new_items.save
end
```

I wanted to destroy `old_items` but when I created new_items they were `old_items == new_items`. Why duplication `#dup` was not working here? How could I split and remove old records? I also tried a transaction (rollback if new_items are invalid), which also did not work.

Comment: Why don't you try using `deep_dup` instead of using `dup`.

Answer (score 3):

`.dup` here duplicates the `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is more of a lazy loading reference to the records than the records themselves.

So when you do `new_item = @user.items.new(item_params)` you are still modifying the collection.

Instead you could do something like this:

```
def my_method
  new_item = @user.items.new(item_params)
  if new_item.save
     @user.items.where.not(id: new_item.id).destroy_all
  end
end
```

But if the user can have only one item, why use a `has_many` and not a `has_one` relation?

You also might want to look into using [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class User
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
end

class Item
  belongs_to :user
end
```

That way you can do:

```
User.find(1).update(items_attributes: [
  { id: 1, _destroy: "1" },
  { name: 'Bob' }
])
```

This example would delete Item 1 and create a new item with the name `Bob`. This makes it easy to create form inputs that lets the user decide which records to keep / destroy.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use a Boolean field for each record called 'is_new'.

All records are created by setting `is_new = true` but before saving this we find the old ones and destroy them with: 
`@user.items.where(is_new: true).destroy_all` 
or setting them to false if you don't need to destroy them.

Answer (score -1):

```
def my_method
  ##create new and delete all except new one
   new_item = @user.items.new(item_params)
  ##any condition that you want to compare
   @user.items.where.not(:item_name=> new_item.name ).destroy_all

end
```

Comment: `Enumerable#delete_if` only removes items from the array - not the database. Its an alias of `reject_if`.

Comment: Still does not work. `new_item` does not have an ID until it is inserted into to the database. You are are also not checking if `new_item` is valid before deleting the others. You should consider spinning up a rails app and actually testing your answers if you are unsure. I'll upvote if you post something that actually works.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of possibilities according the way you want to go. One way could be this one :

```
def my_method
  old_items = get_old_items_ids

  new_item = @user.items.new(item_params)

  if new_item.save
    old_items.delete_old_items 
  end
end

def get_old_items_ids
  @user.items.pluck(:id)
end

def delete_old_items(old_item_ids)
  Items.where(:id => old_item_ids).destroy_all
end
```

Another way could be to compare timestamps of created_at an delete thoses which have been created before now.